# run bat files in multiple command windows (dos shells)

Tags: batch-file

I am new to working with bat files.

I have a program that basically does the following:

- Write multiple bat files in different sub-folders inside a single main folder at once
- The program itself utilizes a command :

  ```
  "start bat_file_name"
  ```

( where bat_file_name is derived from the code say bat1,bat2,bat3)

With this the bat files are executed sequentially one after another in single shell. Is there any modification to the above command with which I can run those bat files in different shells or basically run the files in parallel in separate shells?

Any ideas would be helpful.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `start` command should already do what you need. I've just tried it here and several `start` commands in a batch file ran in parallel.

Comment: My program/code has only one start command not multiple ones, it initiates bat files one by one as per the names passed to it. I would want that for every new bat file a new shell to be opened for run.Is it possible?

Comment: You have to run a separate `start` command for every BAT file to run them in parallel. You can utilize [FOR loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html).